# call a php file who write a cookie, the call is done using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cookies

I'm trying to make a call to a php script who write cookie
and I make the call with jquery (ajax)
here is all my codes:

this is the code who can anyone use to make the call:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.mywebsite.com/generated.js"></script>
<div id="generated"></div>
```

for the file "generated.js", I make the ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({
     url : "generated.php", 
     type : "POST",
     data : "",
     success : function(n){
        $( "#generated" ).html( n );                      } 
 });
 });
```

and here is the "generated.php" where i create the cookie:

```
<?php setcookie("TestCookie", "test"); ?>
```

when i try to use the first code in a html file in the same directory as the other it's working, but when i try to use it in another server it doesn't work, and thanks to all of you

Comment: Are you trying to set a cookie on a different server!? That's VERY not possible.

Comment: yes i try it with javascript, I think it's impossible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a cross domaine restriction i think, you can't call a page outside your domaine via ajax.
a work around is to use CURL.

So your architecture should look's like :

- A JS who call a local php file.
- Your php file will call via CURL your remote file and get response.
- In your ajax done function, you can now    have your page result.

Wish it can helps.